# Alert appearing multiple times in dynamically generated bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-on

I have the following code for a bootstrap datepicker which is dynamically generated.

When the user selects a date it checks to see whether the date picked is allowed (in this case a date prior or equal to the due date) and if not throws an alert.

The problem I'm having is that if the user uses the datepicker say 5 times, the alert appear 5 times if they pick a date which is not allowed.

```
$(document).on('focus', '.start_date', function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
        format: "{{ 'datepicker_format_1'|trans }}",
        startDate: new Date()
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
        var getCompare = $(this).closest(".parent_payment").find("input.due_date");
        getCompare = getCompare.val().split("/");
        getCompare = new Date(getCompare[2], getCompare[1] - 1, getCompare[0]);
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
        if(ev.date > getCompare) {
            $(this).val("");
            alert("The start date can not be after the due date");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You could show the alert on 'blur', the opposite of focus, instead of 'changeDate'. That should fire less frequently.

Comment: I'm hoping for singly rather than just less frequently!

Comment: If you fire it on blur it will show up once when the person is "done" picking the date. No matter how many times they click around within the widget. They'll need to effectively "quit" the widget.